# Separar un print con 3 respuestas

Tags: python

Hola tengo un print con 3 respuestas y estas las quiero poner cada una en una variable alguien sabe como le puedo hacer??
Estoy colocando un split pero me da error

```
print("end", finalLayout)

response = finalLayout
response.split(',')
print(response)
```

**RESPUESTA DE PRINT**

```
end('new-vdttxya0.docx',{
    'A': 'PAGARE',
    'B': 'http://expediente.com/id+11',
    'DEL': '',
    'STS': 'Valid',
    'MSG': 'View current status and electronic document when online'
}, {
'api_version': '2.2',
'scheme': 'C02-HDC-S-B64PNG',
'status': 'C'})
```

**LO QUE NECESITO**

```
layout = 'new-vdttxya0.docx'
content = {
        'A': 'PAGARE',
        'B': 'http://expediente.com/id+11',
        'DEL': '',
        'STS': 'Valid',
        'MSG': 'View current status and electronic document when online'
    }
content2 = {
    'api_version': '2.2',
    'scheme': 'C02-HDC-S-B64PNG',
    'status': 'C'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está es una solución "primitiva", parseando el texto a mano.

```
def parse(texto):
    breaks = [] # indices del texto en donde se detecta un ", {"
    prev = ''   # caracter previo, distinto de espacio
    for i in range(len(texto)):
        if texto[i] == '{' and prev == ',':
            breaks.append(i)
        if not texto[i].isspace():
            prev = texto[i]
    breaks.append(i + 1)

    partes = []
    inicio = 0
    for fin in breaks:
        partes.append(texto[inicio:fin])
        inicio = fin

    return partes
```

La idea es que el texto consiste de diccionarios separados por comas. La función detecta esos puntos (", {"), guardando en la lista `breaks` el indice del "{".

La función luego divide el texto en trozos según los indices en `breaks`.

#### Demo

```
layout = \
"""'new-vdttxya0.docx',{
    'A': 'PAGARE',
    'B': 'http://expediente.com/id+11',
    'DEL': '',
    'STS': 'Valid',
    'MSG': 'View current status and electronic document when online'
}, {
'api_version': '2.2',
'scheme': 'C02-HDC-S-B64PNG',
'status': 'C'}"""

layout, content, content2 = parse(layout)
print(f"layout = {layout}")
print(f"content = {content}")
print(f"content2 = {content2}")
```

produce:

```
layout = 'new-vdttxya0.docx',
content = {
    'A': 'PAGARE',
    'B': 'http://expediente.com/id+11',
    'DEL': '',
    'STS': 'Valid',
    'MSG': 'View current status and electronic document when online'
}, 
content2 = {
'api_version': '2.2',
'scheme': 'C02-HDC-S-B64PNG',
'status': 'C'}

Process finished with exit code 0
```